# Native vs connected vs Composite

Tags: apex, appexchange, app

Could you give me the clarity on the below.

1. My app will comes in which app category(Native vs connected vs Composite )??

We have a free approved app in the appExchange.We have a sales tool which is bulid in php.

If any of our customers want to salesforce sync from our tool,they need to install the app and configure the sync using oauth process.This sync is both way.i.e,Leads can sync from SF to our tool and vice versa.

1. From SF to Our tool sync: We are using Http Callouts
2. From Our tool to SF sync: We are using Salesforce std/custom SOAP/REST API's

Is there any way to get app catageory by seeing my app in appexchange or bulid org.

refer link [here the link](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/wT9jyqKcnm349PxMaD29cp)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Let me cover different APP types

**Native Force.com Applications**

Native Force.com applications are applications built entirely on the salesforce.com platform. They sit inside salesforce infrastructure and are hosted, managed and delivered by salesforce.com. They essentially are salesforce.com.

Native Application data resides in salesforce.com data center.
Your current salesforce administrator can support the application.
No integration is needed – it uses your existing data and set up.

**Connected APP**

A connected app integrates an application with Salesforce using APIs. Connected apps use standard SAML and OAuth protocols to authenticate, provide Single Sign-On, and provide tokens for use with Salesforce APIs. In addition to standard OAuth capabilities, connected apps allow administrators to set various security policies and  have explicit control over who may use the corresponding applications.

**Composite App**

If you use API access then it's a Composite App. As when we move data from Outside Salesforce and use third party then its a composite APP.

As your app is using Third party integration so its a **Composite App**. So in that case you need to clear security review for that as well. for other filter you need to specify that when listing your app in app exchange.

Comment: I got clarity on Native Force.com App,I'm sure my app is not in this category.
My app is using web-services and Salesforce API's and using Connected APP to get the oauth token at initial setup.
I'm thinking my app is under Composite APP.
Could you give me clarity on category of my APP.

Comment: @MadhuNayaki yes I have already mention this that your app is composite.  and the supported Edition and other detail you will specify that when you will list your app in app exchange.

Comment: Thanks for quick help,Yeah its already updated in appexchange.
As recent updates from partner program,there is no scope for free apps in appexchange .Every app pay at least 1$.Let me know the payment is defends on the above mentioned category.have any idea??

Comment: @MadhuNayaki Sorry but I don't have idea about that.